# Python "Expected an indented block" IndentationError?

Tags: python, file, io

I am running into this error with some code I am writing using Scrapy, and I have no clue why it is happening. I have searched for answers on here and elsewhere, and every example I see is someone who didn't indent after an if statement or something like that. That's not the problem I'm having; I get the error for this code:

```
    filename = "output.txt"
    with open(filename, 'rb+') as f:
        f.seek(-1,2)
        last_char = f.read()
```

The error appears on the f.seek(-1,2) line, and I am extremely confused, because it is clearly indented. I assume I'm missing something very obvious, since I haven't programmed in Python in about a year and a half, but any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: Maybe you indent the block with tabs. Try replacing tabs with 4 spaces and see if it helps

Comment: Edit view shows mixed tabs and spaces. Convert all tabs to 4 spaces (your editor should have an option to do that), and don't mix indentation types in the future. Consider running Python with the `-tt` flag to produce more informative error messages in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Few ideas that could help:

Double check your tabs and spaces. Delete from `f.seek(` backwards until it appears right after the `:`, press return once and let your IDE take care of the indentation for you.